# Qt Sort using lessThan is extremely slow

Tags: qt, sorting

I have an QTableView with QSortFilterProxyModel (on QFileSystemModel). I sort it using lessThen comparator like this:

```
bool   SortProxy::lessThan ( const QModelIndex & left, const QModelIndex & right ) const
 {
...
return (collator.compare(left.data().toString(),right.data().toString())) > 0;
... 
}
```

And it works fine for sorting files by name, or filetype. But it works extremely slow on sorting files by name. What to do?

Comment: String comparison is always slow. Consider comparing numbers instead.

Comment: the call to `toString` doesnt heilp either

Comment: When i sort it _by name_ it works well. It slow down only when i try to get date (time) in the lessThen function. Maybe I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: don’t convert datetime objects to QString for comparison, call toDateTime() instead.

Comment: I tried. Still slow. But my variant works perfect... on Ubuntu. But extremely slow on MacOS. :/ Any tricks for OS X?